# WinRT IBackgroundTask Won't Run

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I created an `IBackgroundTask` and when it runs, it kills the app and Visual Studio stops debugging. I can't find a way to see what is causing it. I have turned on `Break when an exception is: CLR Exceptions: Thrown` and it's not breaking. How can I figure out what is causing this error?

Manifest:

```
<Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="Path.To.Task">
  <BackgroundTasks>
    <Task Type="systemEvent" />
  </BackgroundTasks>
</Extension>
```

Task:

```
public class Task : IBackgroundTask
{
    public async void Run( IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance )
    {
        var classA = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ClassA>();
        var classB = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ClassB>();

        var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

        if( classB.Id > 0 )
        {
            await classA.DoStuff( classB.Id );
        }

        deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

Registration:

```
var trigger = new MaintenanceTrigger( 15, false );
BackgroundTaskRegistrar.RegisterBackgroundTask( "Path.To.Task", "Task Name", trigger, null );
```

Task Registrar:

```
public static BackgroundTaskRegistration RegisterBackgroundTask( string taskEntryPoint, string name, IBackgroundTrigger trigger, IBackgroundCondition condition )
{
    foreach( var pair in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks )
    {
        if( pair.Value.Name == name )
        {
            return (BackgroundTaskRegistration)pair.Value;
        }
    }

    var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder
    {
        Name = name, 
        TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint
    };
    builder.SetTrigger( trigger );
    if( condition != null )
    {
        builder.AddCondition( condition );
    }

    var task = builder.Register();

    return task;
}
```

**Update**

I commented out all the code int the tasks and it will dies, so it seems to have nothing to do with the code inside the task.

**Solution**

I was able to find what the error was by enabling logging in the event viewer as specified here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj542416.aspx

What fixed my issue was putting the task into a separate assembly and marking the class that implements `IBackgroundTask` as `sealed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've tried, to make your code run, I had only to add *Reference* to RuntimeComponent (with a BackgroundTask) in my Main Project.

[image]

Note that (you probably now that already) as [MSDN stands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.background.maintenancetrigger.aspx):

> Background tasks that use a maintenance trigger run only when the system is connected to AC power.

Comment: The task is a part of my Windows 8.1 project and not in a separate assembly.

Comment: @JoshClose From what I've read [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977055.aspx#create_the_background_task_class) it must be a Runtime Component. As I've tried it stops working if I place the class in Main Project.

Comment: I'll give that a try. I figured that example just showed putting it in a separate assembly as an example since there are a few extra steps that would be involved.